# Solr string field search with special characters

Tags: java, search, solr

I have just started to work on Solr. There is a phone field and it has been defined in schema like below

```
<field docValues="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true" name="phones" stored="true" type="StrField"/>
```

From my understanding the string field will try to do the exact match but the user can use any format to search the phone number with special characters like (111) 111-1111. So I used ClientUtils.escapeQueryChars to add a slash for the special characters but the search does not result any result. I have been trying to understand why and is there any criteria that special characters cannot be escaped for string field? I don't think tokenizer matters as it is string field and I use edismax parser. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "but the user can use any format to search the phone number". A string field will _only_ give exact matches. It has to be identical in each and every way to get a hit. So if you've indexed `(111) 111-1111`, that's the only value which will give a hit when searching.

Comment: I understand that. But if I escape the characters shouldn’t it work. When I debugged the final value I’m setting in the query is \(111\)111\-1111 and I don’t see any result. But if I search as 1111111111 then I see it. So my question is if I escape the special characters why am I not seeing the expected result.

Comment: What is StrField defined as in your schema? What is the value you've indexed? `1111111111` should not match a string field with the value `(111) 111-1111`. What does debugQuery show? What does the Analysis page show?

Comment: StrField defined as ` <fieldType class="org.apache.solr.schema.StrField" name="StrField"/>`. I know 1111111111 does not match (111)111-1111 but after escaping special characters \(111\)111\-1111 I am not sure why I cannot see a match. In the analysis page I am seeing start:0, end:12, type:word, position:1 and value in raw_bytes. One thing I am seeing is if I use special characters (parantheses and hyphens) in phone field and use fuzzy search (~) then it works after escaping special characters. But if I don't use fuzzy search then I cannot search for exact match escaping special characters.

Comment: Exactly what does your query string look like?

Comment: "rawquerystring": "phones:\\(111\\)1111111",
"querystring": "phones:\\(111\\)1111111",
"parsedquery": "phones:(111)1111111",
"parsedquery_toString": "phones:(111)1111111"
QUERY: q=phones%3A%5C(111%5C)1111111&wt=json&indent=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Solr 7.3.1 I reproduced what you've asked and can confirm that as long as you escape `(`, `)` and  properly, you'll get the hits you're looking for.

**Schema**

- id: string
- phones: string (multivalued, docvalues, indexed, stored)

**Documents**

```
{
  "id":"doc1",
  "phones":["(111) 111-1111"],
  "_version_":1602190176246824960
},
{
  "id":"doc2",
  "phones":["111 111-1111"],
  "_version_":1602190397829808128
},
{
  "id":"doc3",
  "phones":["111 (111)-1111"],
  "_version_":1602190400002457600
}
```

**Query**

*`/select?q=phones:\(111\)\ 111-1111`*

```
{
    "id":"doc1",
    "phones":["(111) 111-1111"],
    "_version_":1602190176246824960}]
}
```

*`/select?debugQuery=on&q=phones:111\ 111-1111`*

```
{
    "id":"doc2",
    "phones":["111 111-1111"],
    "_version_":1602190397829808128}]
}
```

*`/select?debugQuery=on&q=phones:1111111111`*

```
"response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]}
```

The behavior is exactly as described - exact matches only.

**Getting the behavior you want with `PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory`**

Let's create a custom field type that removes anything that's not a number or letter:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:application/json' --data-binary '{
  "add-field-type" : {
     "name":"phoneStripped",
     "class":"solr.TextField",
     "positionIncrementGap":"100",
     "analyzer" : {
        "charFilters":[{
           "class":"solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory",
           "replacement":"",
           "pattern":"[^a-zA-Z0-9]"
        }],
        "tokenizer":{
           "class":"solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" 
        },
     }
  }
}' http://localhost:8983/solr/foo/schema
```

Then we create a new field named `phone_stripped` using this new field type (you can do this in the UI), and reindex our documents - now using the new field name:

```
  {
    "id":"doc1",
    "phone_stripped":"(111) 111-1111"
  },
  {
    "id":"doc3",
    "phone_stripped":"111 (111)-1111"
  },
  {
    "id":"doc2",
    "phone_stripped":"111 111-1111"
  }
```

And then we search for just `1111111111`:

```
"response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[ .. all our docs ..]
```

Using the previous search, `phone_stripped:\(111\)\ 111-1111`:

```
"response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[ .. all our docs ..]
```

And just to make sure we haven't broken things in unspeakable ways, let's search  for `phone_stripped:\(111\)\ 111-1112`:

```
"response":{"numFound":0,"start":0,"docs":[]
```

Comment: Ok. I think I understand now. So in your example if the document is stored with the phone number as 1111111111 and if the user want to search using parentheses like (111)111-1111 then I am assuming I have to replace or remove the special characters before doing a search, is that correct or any better ideas?

Comment: That is correct - which is why I asked if you _really_ wanted exact matches in my first comment. If you want to match regardless of how the user types the phone number, you can use a [PatternReplaceCharFilter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/charfilterfactories.html#CharFilterFactories-solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory) to remove any characters that is not a number (`[^0-9]`) (or if you allow letters, anything that's not a letter or a number - `[^a-zA-Z0-9]`).

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example showing what you probably want.

Comment: Thanks! very helpful.